# Is there a way in batch to identify a number or I have to use a lot os ifs

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So my problem is that I don't wanna play barchoba with my program and ask if the variable1 ends with 1 or 2 or so on...
Can you please show me a trick, how to aks my program about the ending digit of my variable?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `%variable:~-1%` expands to the last character of `%variable1%` you can use the `GEq`, *(Greater than or Equal to)*, and `LEq`, *(Less than or Equal to)*, comparators to test it against.

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Undefine variables
Set "variable1="
Set "digit="

Rem Ask for the variable string value
Set /P "variable1=Please enter your variable string value: "

Rem Test if the variable string value ends with a digit
If "%variable1:~-1%" GEq "0" If "%variable1:~-1%" LEq "9" Set "digit=%variable1:~-1%"
If Defined digit (Echo variable1 ends with a %digit%) Else Echo variable1 does not end with a digit

Rem Add a delay to read the Echo message
Timeout 3 >Nul
```

Comment: Your `Else` part does _not_ work as intended because it just apply to _the second_ `if`. If the last character is `@` (for example, there are many) this code show nothing! It would be necessary to repeat the `else` part for the _first_ if, with nested parentheses...

Comment: @Aacini, thanks I've edited my answer to use a slightly different method.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem Initialize digits just once, at beginning
set "digits=0123456789"


rem Test if "variable1" ends in any digit
if "!digits:%variable1:~-1%=!" neq "%digits%" (
   echo Variable1 ends in digit
) else (
   echo Variable1 does not end in digit
)
```

The method takes the *last character* of variable1: `%variable1:~-1%` and try to *eliminate it* from digits variable: `"!digits:V=!"`. If the result is *different* than the original value of digits variable: `"%digits%"`, then the character was a digit indeed...

Note that you need to `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` for this method to work...

Comment: This fails with syntax error when the last character is a double quote. Some additional escaping is required.